# DynamoDB API in Serverless

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-sdk-js

I'm using serverless framework to create an application that writes and reads data from DynamoDB. I follow their [official docs](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-express-rest-api/) and look into other examples on [github](https://github.com/serverless/examples/tree/master/aws-node-rest-api-with-dynamodb).

As far as I understand Serverless uses AWS SDK for NodeJS under the hood.

I noticed the DynamoDB API Difference in Serverless and official AWS SDK.

1. Method names. They are different: in the official AWS SDK docs for reading there's a `getItem` method ([link for the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#getItem-property)), whereas in the Serveless `get` method is being used ([link](https://github.com/serverless/examples/blob/master/aws-node-rest-api-with-dynamodb/todos/get.js#L16)) everywhere.
2. Params definition:

In accordance to the official documentation I need to use the following convention to create params:

```
var params = {
  Key: {
    UserId: {
      S: '123456'
    }
  },
  TableName: 'Users'
};

dynamodb.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
   ...
})
```

However, Serverless shows a different approach:

```
const params = {
  Key: {
    UserId: '123456'
  },
  TableName: 'Users'
}

dynamoDb.get(params, (error, result) => {}
```

**Question:** Could somebody please explain the difference and why is that? It's a little bit confusing and hard to understand which convention to follow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few hours of research, I found why.

All examples that are shown in Serverless docs use specific class [`DocumentClient`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html) that simplifies development in javascript world by omitting DynamoDB datatypes.

Methods and parameters they accept are also different so that it's possible to send/retrieve data without specifying a datatype. However, in the end, DynamoDB still requires types, but all conversion is happening behind the scenes.